# What is the intended purpose of the _wp_attachment_context post meta key?

Tags: php

If the `$context` variable isn't empty inside `wp_insert_attachment()`, post meta info gets added with a meta key of `_wp_attachment_context`. What is the intended purpose of `_wp_attachment_context`? For example, can someone give some examples of the meta values I might store with this key?

Answer (score 1):

After a little more research, I found out that WordPress stores values such as custom-header and custom-background against the meta key. I guess it's a way to distinguish them from the rest of the attachments in the system.

Comment: So what exactly does custom-header mean in wp? What does it mean if it has _wp_attached_file postmeta that is a serialized WP_Error?